# Why do we need /lib in linux in 3.* kernel?

Tags: linux, fedora, file-management, libraries

I have a host installed with fedora19 64bit, I saw the directory of /lib and /lib64. In fhs, it says, normally, /lib is a link to /lib64 or /lib32, but it seems not in fedora or other linux dist with 3.* kernel. I saw the files in /lib just have some directories and most of them are 64bit elf too, why is this happening? Where should we find and place the libraries when we are writing a program? thanks.

Comment: I would create a directory under /usr/local/lib/projectname  Then add this location to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig   At least until the project is far enough along to be in beta.

Comment: Nothing puts libraries in /lib except for system tools needed to boot the system.  Your libraries are installed in /usr/lib* when packaged or /usr/local/lib* when installed manually.